# How to check login username and set a dynamic role in SSAS multidimensional

Tags: ssas

I have a dimension which contains our business warehouse IDs and also I made users in Active Directory with the same name(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, …) as you see in below.

DimWarehouse

```
  ID
       1001
       1002
       1003
       1004
       .
       .
       .
```

My question is that how it is possible each "username" just access to it's Warehouse ID?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your questions, you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways how you can restrict user access to certain parts of the cube:

- You define "**static security**": You define one role in the cube for each set of permissions (if I understand your requirements correctly, that would mean one role per user), and then you map the Active Directory users or user groups to those roles. If you have many users and many permission roles, that can get more or less unmanageable. However, sometimes it is good that you also can use AD user groups for this purpose, and that can reduce effort a lot. I Implemented a solution like this where we needed to restrict access user access based on their country, and only had around 50 countries, and AD user groups were already existing for the countries.
- You can use "**dynamic security**". This means you only use a single role and write an MDX expression that most likely makes use of the [`Username()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/username-mdx) MDX function, and which returns a valid MDX set which is either a set of allowed or a set of forbidden members. As your MDX statement could even call an AS Stored procedure implemented in .net, you are even more flexible, as this .net Stored procedure could e. g. contact your AD to check for further properties of the user.

In both cases, you would administer the settings in "dimension security" of the cube design in "SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence" or in SQL Server Management Studio, and would need to design your cube accordingly to have the correct relations from the dimension that you restrict to your data.

A detailed (if a bit old) blog post describing an approach for setting security using dynamic security can be found at http://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.com/2016/07/dynamic-security-in-ssas-in-detail.html.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are driven by [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/roles-and-permissions-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions).

You may need to create multiple roles and assign users to each of the roles.

Then for each role, you define which dimension attributes are accessible to that role.

[image]